# Calculating distance and subsetting with multiple for loops

Tags: r

Everyone. I'm trying to filter GPS location data based on distance (UTMs) and time (H:M:S) criteria independently and concurrently. Here's the data structure:

```
head(collar)
FID  animal      date       time        zone easting northing
1    URAM01_2012 6/24/2012  10:00:00 AM 13S  356664  3971340
2    URAM01_2012 6/24/2012  1:02:00 PM  13S  356760  3971480
3    URAM01_2012 6/24/2012  4:01:00 PM  13S  357482  3972325
4    URAM01_2012 6/24/2012  7:01:00 PM  13S  356882  3971327
5    URAM01_2012 6/25/2012  4:01:00 AM  13S  356574  3971765
6    URAM01_2012 6/25/2012  7:01:00 AM  13S  357796  3972231
```

Right now I'm filtering by distance only but I'm having some issues. The code should calculate the distance between FID[1] and FID[2] and then assign that distance to FID[1] in a new column ($step.length). After all distances have been calculated, the data is then subsetted based on a distance rule. Right now I have it set to where I want all locations that are >200m apart. Once subsetted, the process is then repeated until the distance between all subsequent locations is >200m. Here's the code that I've written that accomplishes only a portion of what I'd like to do:

```
reps <- 10
 #Begin loop for the number of reps. Right now it's at 10 just to see if the code works.
for(rep in 1:reps){

  #Begin loop for the number of GPS locations in the file
  for(i in 1:length(collar$FID)){

    #Calculate the distance between a GPS location and the next GPS locations. the formula is the hypotenuse of the Pythagorean theorem. 
    collar$step.length[i] <- sqrt(((collar$easting[i] - collar$easting[i+1])^2) + ((collar$northing[i] - collar$northing[i+1])^2))

  }

  #Subset the data. Select all locations that are >200m from the next GPS location.
  collar <- subset(collar, step.length >200) 

}
```

Now, the code isn't perfect and I would like to add 2 conditions into the code.

1.) Animal ID isn't considered. Therefore, a distance for the last location of an animal will be generated using the first location of a new animal when the distance should be NA. I thought using for(i in 1:unique(collar$animal)) might work, but it didn't (shocking) and I'm not sure what to do since for(i in length(collar$animal)) doesn't use only unique values.

2.) I'd also like to insert a break in the for loop when all locations that are >200m. I'm sure there has to be a better way of doing this, but I thought I'd set reps to something large (e.g., 10000) and once a criteria was met then R would break:

```
if(collar$step.length > 200){
   break }
```

Yet, since the if condition is >1 only the first element is used. I've haven't thought about time or distance/time yet, but if anyone has any suggestions for those endeavors, I'd appreciate the advice. Thanks for your help and guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you are trying to do with the reps but you can take advantage of the `split` and `unsplit` functions to focus on each individual animal.

First I created a `distance()` function that finds the columns named easting and northing from the object to create a vector of distances. Then we split collar up by the animal, and apply the `distance` function to each animal. We add this list of distances to the list of animals with some `mapply` code and then `unsplit` the results to make everything go back together.

Let me know what you want to do with the ">200" step.

```
distance <- function(x){
  easting <- x$easting
  northing <- x$northing
  easting2 <- c(easting[-1], NA)
  northing2 <- c(northing[-1], NA)
  sqrt((easting - easting2)^2 + (northing - northing2)^2)
}
s <- split(collar, collar$animal)
distances <- lapply(s, distance)
s2 <- mapply(cbind, s, "Distance" = distances, SIMPLIFY = F)
collar.new <- unsplit(s2, collar$animal)
```

**EDIT:**

Apologies if this is cumbersome, I'm sure I can get it shorter but as of now let me know if it works for you. I would also be curious to see how fast it runs as I have been making up my own data.

```
filterout <- function(input, value = NULL){
  # requirements of the input object
  stopifnot(all(c("FID","animal","easting","northing") %in% colnames(input)))
  distance <- function(x){  # internal distance function
    e1 <- x$easting; e2 <- c(NA, e1[-nrow(x)])
    n1 <- x$northing; n2 <- c(NA, n1[-nrow(x)])
    sqrt((e1 - e2)^2 + (n1 - n2)^2)
  }
  nc <- ncol(input) # save so we can "rewrite" Distance values each reiteration
  f <- function(input){ # the recursive function (will run until condition is met)
    z <- split(input[,-(nc+1)], input$animal) # split by animal & remove (if any) prior Distance column
    distances <- lapply(z, distance) # collect distances
    z2 <- mapply(cbind, z, "Distance" = distances, SIMPLIFY = F) # attach distances
    r1 <- lapply(z2, function(x) { # delete first row under criteria
      a <- x$Distance < value # CRITERIA
      a[is.na(a)] <- FALSE # Corrects NA values into FALSE so we don't lose them
      first <- which(a == T)[1] # we want to remove one at a time 
      `if`(is.na(first), integer(0), x$FID[first]) # returns FIDs to remove
    })
    z3 <- unsplit(z2, input$animal)
    # Whether to keep going or not
    if(length(unlist(r1)) != 0){ # if list of rows under criteria is not empty
      remove <- which(z3$FID %in% unlist(r1, use.names = F)) # remove them 
      print(unlist(r1, use.names = F)) # OPTIONAL*** printing removed FIDs
      f(z3[-remove,]) # and run again
    } else {
      return(z3) # otherwise return the final list
    }
  }
  f(input)
}
```

And the function can be used as follows:

```
filterout(input = collar, value = 200)
filterout(input = collar, value = 400)
filterout(input = collar, value = 600)
```

**EDIT2:**

I opened up a bounty question to figure out how to do a certain step but hopefully this answer helps. It might take a little ~ a minute to do 37k rows but let me know~

```
x <- collar

skipdistance <- function(x, value = 200){
  d <- as.matrix(dist(x[,c("easting","northing")]))
  d[lower.tri(d)] <- 0
  pick <- which(d > value, arr.ind = T) # pick[order(pick[,"row"]),] # visual clarity

  findConnectionsBase <- function(m) {
    n <- nrow(m)
    myConnections <- matrix(integer(0), nrow = n, ncol = 2)
    i <- j <- 1L
    k <- 2L
    while (i <= n) {
      myConnections[j, ] <- m[i, ]
      while (k <= n && m[i, 2] != m[k, 1]) {k <- k + 1L}
      i <- k
      j <- j + 1L
    }
    myConnections[!is.na(myConnections[,1]), ]
  }

  keep.ind <- findConnectionsBase(pick)
  keep.row <- unique(c(keep.ind))
  cbind(x[keep.row,], Distance = c(NA,d[keep.ind]))
}

a <- do.call(rbind,lapply(split(x, x$animal), skipdistance, value = 200))
dim(a)
```

**Edit #3:**

```
library(lubridate) # great package for string -> dates

# changed to give just rows that satisfy greater than value criteria
skip <- function(dist.var, value = 200){
  d <- as.matrix(dist(dist.var))
  d[lower.tri(d)] <- 0
  pick <- which(d > value, arr.ind = T) # pick[order(pick[,"row"]),] # visual clarity
  findConnectionsBase <- function(m) {
    n <- nrow(m)
    myConnections <- matrix(integer(0), nrow = n, ncol = 2)
    i <- j <- 1L
    k <- 2L
    while (i <= n) {
      myConnections[j, ] <- m[i, ]
      while (k <= n && m[i, 2] != m[k, 1]) {k <- k + 1L}
      i <- k
      j <- j + 1L
    }
    myConnections[!is.na(myConnections[,1]), ]
  }
  unique(c(findConnectionsBase(pick)))
}

collar <- structure(list(FID = 1:8, animal = c("URAM01_2012", "URAM01_2012", "URAM01_2012", "URAM01_2012", "URAM01_2013", "URAM01_2013", "URAM01_2013", "URAM01_2013"), date = c("6/24/2012", "6/24/2012", "6/24/2012", "6/24/2012", "6/25/2012", "6/25/2012", "6/25/2012", "6/25/2012"  ), time = c("10:00:00AM", "1:02:00PM", "4:01:00PM", "7:01:00PM", "4:01:00AM", "7:01:00AM", "7:01:00AM", "7:01:00AM"), zone = c("13S", "13S", "13S", "13S", "13S", "13S", "13S", "13S"), easting = c(356664L, 
 356760L, 356762L, 356882L, 356574L, 357796L, 357720L, 357300L), northing = c(3971340L, 3971480L, 3971498L, 3971498L, 3971765L, 3972231L, 3972230L, 3972531L)), .Names = c("FID", "animal", "date", "time", "zone", "easting", "northing"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))


collar[skip(dist.var = collar[,c("easting","northing")], 
            value = 200),]
# dist function works on dates, but it makes sense to convert to hours 
dist(lubridate::mdy_hms(paste(collar$date, collar$time)))
hours <- 2.99
collar[ skip(dist.var = lubridate::mdy_hms(paste(collar$date, collar$time)),
             value = hours * 3600), ]
```

Comment: Huh. Very interesting. It's always neat seeing different ways of solving a problem. First off, thanks for your help, @efriedland. I really appreciate it.

First off, 200 is the distance (meters) I am currently using to decide if a location should stay or not. I'll also increase that distance to 400 m, 600 m, etc in future trials. The purpose of this is to try and eliminate spatial autocorrelation between locations.

Comment: Now, if the code runs once, then each point has a pairwise distance with the following point. After deleting points that are <200 m, there will still be locations within the dataset that are <200 m. For example, pt1 is 100 m from pt2 and 175 m from point 3. After the first round of filtering, the code will have to be run again to generate the distance between pt1 and pt3 (175 m) with pt3 being deleted after subsetting again. That's what `reps` is for. To start the entire process over again. At some time period, all sequential locations should be >200 m from each other.

Comment: I'm taking a stab at this now. In  your example pt1 -> pt2 is 100m, so we put the distance value on the pt1 row. but we want to delete pt2... What would you say about putting the 100m meter on pt2 and leaving NA on pt1 as the start?

Comment: Great, no problem, I will come back to this in a few hours - i have started making a function so you can specify the value you desire (200, 400, 600) and will record the number of iterations necessary to remove all step points under your value

Comment: Wow. This is phenomenal. Thanks again. 

The code works beautifully, however, when I try it on the full data set (~36k locations) there's an error. 

`Error: node stack overflow`
`Error during wrapup: node stack overflow`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151517/discussion-between-evan-friedland-and-matt-gould).

Comment: Hey! I just ran the code and it successfully filtered ~36,000 locations to ~14,000 in roughly 50 minutes.I really appreciate your time and efforts on this project. This will save me a lot of time and headaches! I was thinking it would be possible to just modify the qualifiers in the code to filter by time and distance+time. In general, do you see any major issues I might run into during that task?

Comment: Just edited the function to be a little faster - I will take a look at doing that this weekend. Because this runs off of the results of a `dist()` function, it might be a few steps to apply that to other variables - but definitely possible.

Comment: Thanks again, Evan.

Comment: Totally spaced on this- will look tonight

Comment: Sorry, I didn't receive a notification to your edit. I'll look the code over and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: Hey Evan, what size of data.frame did you use? I'm having issues where R "cannot allocate vector of size 5.0 Gb." I've tried subsettin by year, but even that was throwing the same error.

Comment: Yeah if the data is big that makes it hard to keep it all in memory... maybe cut it in half and use the function on both pieces? XD

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks and shout out to Evan for all of his hard work. Obviously, the code that he generated is a bit different than what I proposed, but that's the great thing about this community; sharing unique solutions ourselves may not think come to. See Edit #2 for the final code which filters GPS collar data by the distance between consecutive points.